# about Environment.SpecialFolder

Tags: c#, winforms, special-folders

I want to access my "My documents" folder from my WinForms ToolStrip menu. I am populating ToolStrip with a XML file.
I am storing `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` in my XML file. It is throwing an error.

Can anyone please help?.

This is part of my xml file.

```
<item name="MSPowerpoint" action="%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office\office11\POWERPNT.exe" parameters="/n"/>
<item name="MyDocuments" action="Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal" parameters=""/>    
<item name="" text="-" />
```

This is the method to start applicatons.

```
public void startapp(string s)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo pst = new ProcessStartInfo();

        pst.UseShellExecute = true;
        pst.FileName = s;
        Process.Start(pst);            
    }
```

This is the error i am getting..
"The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Please also post the error details (at least the error message).

Comment: [tinyurl.com/so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a way to evaluate the path before you start the process: you're getting the error 'cannot find the file specified' because the operating system is being literal and looking for a directory or file called '`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`' and not the actual directory this represents.

Some kind of encoding might work, so instead of putting `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` in the XML, put in a string representing that value - e.g. '#MYDOCUMENTS' - instead, then when the ToolStrip is created you can extract the values.

```
// For example:

string fileName = GetFileNameFromXml(); // Or however you get it
if (fileName == "#MYDOCUMENTS")
{ 
    fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
}

startapp(fileName);
```

Comment: thankyou very much
i  evaluated Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) in my method.it is perfectly working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting? And seems you have missing

> )

in the XML File.

> action="Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal"